# Django,page not found 404

Tags: python, django

When I start developement server

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

Then

```
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^admin/
^blog/
The empty path didn't match any of these.
```

mysite.urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
 url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
 url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

blog/urls.py

```
pp_name = 'blog'
urlpatterns = [
# post views
url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/'\
r'(?P<post>[-\w]+)/$',
views.post_detail,
name='post_detail'),
]
```

I suspect something is wrong with my templates
This is what tree gives

```
tree mysite
mysite
├── blog
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-36.pyc
│   │       └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── admin.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── models.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── blog
│   │       ├── base.html
│   │       └── post
│   │           ├── detail.html
│   │           └── list.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
└── mysite
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    │   ├── settings.cpython-36.pyc
    │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
    │   └── wsgi.cpython-36.pyc
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your urls not matching the `/` path in main urls. Add some view to url regex `r'^$'` then it will work. For example take a view named `home`.
please import related imports.

```
from . import views    

urlpatterns = [ 
        url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

or you can do like

```
urlpatterns = [ 
     url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
     url(r'^', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Take a look at me edit I have views in my blog/urls.py

Comment: @RichardRublev your pattern `url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),` will match url `/blog/` not `/`.

Answer (score 1):

To use root site path you should change urlpatterns to this:

```
urlpatterns = [
 url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
 url(r'^', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

Otherwise you still can get your view calling `http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog` url.